# Multiplying Hours & Mins by Hourly Rate

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL database that records the number of hours worked on various clients.  It has two tables, one storing the hours, and another holds the different rates I charge for work at each client.

I have a webpage that presents the data in a tabled format showing Start / Stop Time, Activity, Calculated **Hours**, **Rate** and a couple of other info calls.

The **Hours** column is calculated using `TIME_FORMAT( TIMEDIFF( end_date, start_date ) ,  '%h %i' ) AS Hours` which works fine, giving me the hours/mins worked.  However the Amount column is only showing the Hours * Rate calculation rather than Hours&Min*Rate.

How do I include the minutes?

`TIME_FORMAT( TIMEDIFF( end_date, start_date ) ,  '%h %i' ) * rate`  ... is what I am using right now to calculate the total amount but as I said the minutes value is ignored.

Appreciate any help, regards Roddy

Comment: Surely you want fractions of an hour (in base 10) rather than 'minutes' per se!?!?!?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `TIMEDIFF`, use [`TIMESTAMPDIFF`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff) which gives you the difference in a measure that you specify (seconds, hours, years). Use it like this in your query:

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF( MINUTE , start_date, end_date ) * ( rate / 60 ) AS billable_amount
FROM  `your_table`
```

Answer (score 2):

`'%h %i'` will result in something like `17 15` – that is a *string* value, and not something that can be multiplied with another number.

Use `TIMESTAMPDIFF` with unit `MINUTE` instead of `TIME_FORMAT`, or, if that doesn’t work (because according to docs it needs full date values), `TIME_TO_SEC` (and divide by 60).

Comment: making in concrete, assuming rate is hourly: TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, start_date, end_date) * (rate / 60)

Comment: TIMESTAMPDIFF WORKED PERFECTLY - THANKYOU

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT TIME(NOW());
+-------------+
| TIME(NOW()) |
+-------------+
| 16:29:13    |
+-------------+

SELECT TIME_TO_SEC(TIME(NOW()))/3600;
+-------------------------------+
| TIME_TO_SEC(TIME(NOW()))/3600 |
+-------------------------------+
|                       16.4875 |
+-------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

If your total time value is stored in format 00:00 and the hourly rate in format 00.00 you can use the following query to return value with 2 decimals;

```
SELECT ROUND(SUM( TIME_TO_SEC('time') * ('hourly_rate')))/60/60 AS 'total_value' FROM 'table'
```